# PhpMyAdmin connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect my Database on PhpMyAdmin with my webPage. However I keep getting this error:

```
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

My code (php) is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_client2";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

I do not understand what is wrong: 
[enter image description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYBYy.png
```

Hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please give context to what your image is showing (for example, by including the table headers, or where the screenshot is coming from).

Answer (score 0):

Please enter a password to the phpcode  $password = "";

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin disabled root login by default.

If you want to allow root login you will have to update  /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = TRUE;
```

Also mysql change the ability to login from root out of the shell.
please see this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7

The recommendation is to create an account other than root and grant all privileges.